# Чем рефакторинг отличается от переписывания? Где граница между двумя этими процессами?

Tags: архитектура, рефакторинг

Интересует само понятие рефакторинга.

Не понятно, что означает в определении "без изменения функциональности". Если я придумал новую архитектуру (*например она была на функциях, а я придумал на классах*), на имеющиеся фичи - это уже можно назвать переписыванием? Или так-как результат работы заново написанной программы остаётся прежним, то это всё-равно рефакторинг?

Comment: Приведи полное определение и откуда ты его взял

Comment: @Grundy а на что влияет это? Это классическое понятие рефакторинга.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в принципе на все виляет. Не зная, что именно было в определении кроме _без изменения функциональности_ невозможно установить границы

Comment: @Grundy таких определений много и они однотипны:  https://www.google.com/search?q=рефакторинг+это+без+изменения+функциональности&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruRU835RU835&oq=рефакторинг+это+без+изменения+функциональности&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i546l4.2879j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а может быть в этом случае было не однотипное :)

Comment: *`"Или так-как результат работы заново написанной программы остаётся прежним, то это всё-равно рефакторинг?"`* -- именно так. Под функциональностью подразумевается набор действий (*функциональная спецификация*), а не их внутренняя реализация